# Motion detection camera

Tags: equipment-recommendation, wifi, motion

I am looking for a camera that offers two features (or I guess 3).

- The first feature is that it needs to be able to either have a motion
  detector, or be compatible with one so that it captures a photo when
  motion is detected
- Secondly this however should at most be 1 picture every 10(20/30) seconds
- And thirdly the camera should have some sort of way to automatically either upload by WIFI or be able to take photos while being connected to a computer so that photos can be moved right after being taken.

If anyone has a tip on how to find what I'm looking for, or even knows a device help would greatly be appreciated!

Edit: I will consider the PI option.

Edit2: I guess simple motion detection wouldnt work, as the objects will be moving on a conveyor belt and that would always trigger the motion detection. Any other ideas anyone? Also really sorry for being so vague, I dont really know anything photography.

Comment: Google for *motion detector shutter release*

Comment: Are you looking for a *security camera*?

Comment: @xiota I don't think OP is, a security camera with 0.1-0.033 FPS would be rather useless

Comment: A security camera doesn't need to be recording *all* the time, only when there is something of interest happening, such as when motion is detected.

Comment: Or maybe a trail camera, for photographing wild life when motion is detected?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a [game/trail camera](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=game+trail+camera). Otherwise you can cook up something with a webcam and a RaspberryPi, google for `raspberry pi sprinkler cat`.

Comment: @xiota No, but OP specifically requests *at most 1 picture every 10(20/30) seconds*. A trail camera seems plausible

Comment: Hi, welcome to Photo-SE. Can you describe what is your _intended use_ of the camera you spec'd? I mean, a solution can be put together with hobby electronics fairly easily (for someone familiar with said hobby electronics). But we don't know if that meets your needs. That is, what problem is the camera you find supposed to solve for you?

Comment: You should probably look at a Raspberry Pi & camera with something called motionEyeOS.  It sounds like it does what you want (or very nearly does everything your want). Software is freely available from github.

Comment: Hi first of all, im sorry for the late response. Im not looking for a security camera, but the idea with a 'motion detector shutter release' helped me a lot.

Comment: The camera will be used to produce images for automatic detection of faulty products on a production lines, meaning the images should be passed into a neural network pipeline.

Comment: Since you are not interested in the photo, but instead with the analysis of the object on the belt, you should research computer vision in manufacturing.  Lots of info on that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about the photography, but instead about the detection. That a camera is involved is really unrelated to this board

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't give any information about desired camera specs, but the cheapest and easiest route might be to use a webcam such as the [Wyze](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076H3SRXG).

It takes pictures (or video) when motion is detected.

It takes a picture at a settable rate (I think).

It uploads images in real time to a remote server as well as a built in memory card. You can get to them via an iPhone or iPad. You can also get to them via a PC but it requires some [trickery](https://forums.wyzecam.com/t/viewing-wyze-cameras-on-the-pc/12792).

It automatically (or manually) switches to IR and has built-in illuminators.

It runs off of USB power.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this actually does what I want. In general I would prefer something a lot more powerful. Also do you know if there is a way to have it only snap at most one picture in an interval of time?